# Как правильно поступить, если close() был прерван сигналом (errno EINTR)?

Tags: c, signal

В документции сказано, что в зависимости от реализвации, если close() был прерван сигналом, то файловый дескриптор может остаться открытым или быть закрыт.

Я теряюсь в догадках. В сети нашёл некоторую информацию и нашёл упоминание того, что на практике такое практически не возможно, но всё равно не убедило.

Собственно, 3 вопроса:

1. Есть ли аналог close(), который не имеет подобных проблем?
2. Есть ли способ проверить, закрылся ли на самом деле дескриптор или нет, не вызывая close() повторно?
3. Есть ли способ "переименовать" fd? То есть изменить саму цифру.

Comment: *`"Есть ли способ проверить...."`*  -- например, вызовите [fcntl(fd, GETFD)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) и если вернет -1, то см. errno (EBADF был закрыт)

Comment: Не поможет. Это сработает только в том случае, если дескриптор был закрыт и за время между вызовами close и fcntl не был открыт другой файл или сокет.

Comment: А вы сами не знаете что творите в своей программе? (ваши fd управляются исключительно вашим кодом процесса, а не неизвестно как работающими демонами)

Comment: У меня многопоточная программа. Например, в тот момент, когда в одном потоке я закрываю файл, в другом потоке может открыться сокет. Если close() вападет с ошибкой EINTR, то тут 2 варианта - либо файл остаётся открытым, и тогда сокет займёт следующий дескриптор, либо файл закроется и сокет займёт его дескриптор. Весь сыр-бор как раз из-за подобных моментов.

Comment: Понятно. В подобной ситуации ничего кроме отслеживания полученных fd, скажем связанных с последовательно увеличивающимся их счетчиком (этот механизм придется загнать под mutex) и анализа, не получил ли кто-то уже тот же fd, в голову не приходит. (Этот геморрой точно отвратит вас от mutithreading в сторону либо forks либо event-driving (async files/sockets)). (Я не знаю как хорошо решить вашу проблему, но попробуйте задать вопрос немного по другому -- `как оределить, что тот же fd связан уже с новым объектом?` (подозреваю, что можно поанализировать результат вызова fstat))

Comment: А есть ли способ изменить номер fd? Наподобие dup2(), только не создать копию, именно изменить номер.

Comment: читаю доку, там сказано, что не обдуманно выполнять команду `close`, так-как другие процессы могут получить тот-же файловый дескриптор, и получится `race condition`. Тогда может быть сделать просто `fsync`?

Comment: @AlexGlebe сделать можно, но гарантирует ли это невозможность возникновения ошибки с EINTR?

Comment: @AlexGlebe, в общем случае ничто не запрещает иметь несколько fd и закрывать их. Устройство будет закрыто, когда закрыт последний fd. (там (в блоке управления устройством) есть счетчик ссылок). / @-64-core, вообще, imho, для практического решения стоит обсудить конкретный сценарий (файлы, сокеты, какой thread и когда что конкретно делает)

Comment: @avp но сама проблема всё равно останется. Похоже, что вызов close() - это сам по себе UB. Я вообще теперь подумываю в качестве надёжного решения делать форк, в дочернем процессе открывать дескриптор, делать всю работу, передавать данные в основной поток, а потом просто выходить из дочернего процесса. По крайней мере, не будет никаких подводных камней.

Comment: @64-coreCPU, конечно, все зависит от алгоритма обработки ваших данных. Но смотрите, если типы fd, который вы закрываете и возможного дубликата, получаемого в др. thread **разные** (скажем, один `S_ISREG`, а другой `S_ISSOCK`), то вопрос с дубликатом решается вызовом fstat() после неудачного close(). Если fstat() == -1 и errno == EBADF, то close закрыл fd. Еlse если fstat() == 0 и типы разные, то тоже закрыл, но появился "дубликат". Как-то так

Comment: @avp это частично решит проблему, спасибо.